# Is there a way to preserve the formatting of inline images in emails in Outlook for Mac?

Tags: mac, email, ms-office

At my office, most users are PC based. However, a few teams have Macs. The standard email tool is Outlook, and the Mac users have Outlook for Mac.

When someone sends me an email that has images pasted inline with the text, all of the images are stripped out, replaced with an icon of a question mark, and added as attachments.

I've done a bit of research, and it seems the reason this happens is because Outlook on Windows defaults to sending an email in RTF format. Outlook for Mac doesn't use RTF, so it converts it to HTML format. If someone sends me an HTML email, I see the images inline without any issues.

So I wonder, aside from asking everyone in the organization to change their email format to HTML, is there a way to preserve the inline images and formatting of the RTF email?

Comment: Mail for OSX open it properly. Reallistically Office for Mac has not been a priority for Microsoft in the last few decades and I stay way from them. The only produt still not comparable to the MS one is Word

Comment: Thanks @RuiFRibeiro for the comment. I'm kind of stuck with Outlook for Mac, so I'm trying to make the best of it and see if there are any plugins, tools, or settings to help alleviate the pain! :)